# dir permissions: delete enclosed files but not create or write to files

Tags: permissions, xattr

I want the following situation for a user's directory:

- user can list files
- user can read files
- user can delete files
- user cannot add files
- (ideally, also) user cannot modify files

I haven't been able to think of a way to do this with permissions and xattrs. Any thoughts? The file system types in use are NFS v3 and GPFS. The OS is RHEL 7 Linux.

Comment: I really doubt this will be possible since creating files and deleting files are both "write" operations on the directory. I don't think you can allow one and not the other. But, just in case it is actually possible, please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using.

Comment: Would you accept a custom tool (i.e. instead of `rm`) to delete files? That's the only way I can see this is possible. It could be broadly similar in use to `rm`, just not called `rm`.

Comment: Yes, I could accept a separate tool to remove files. But not one that uses suid root.

Comment: It would have to be suid/sgid to either owner or group that had write permission to the _directory_ owning the files

Comment: What about with the use of ACLs?

Comment: I could create a python program wrapping rm that runs setgid and use ACLs to add that group rw to all the user's files in the dir. Sound reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this using fileset quota. Make the directory a fileset:

```
cd /gpfs/gpfs0/subdirectoryY/
mmcrfileset gpfs0 testfileset
mmlinkfileset gpfs0 testfileset
```

Create all the files you want, then set the quota for number of files for the fileset to 1:

```
# mmsetquota gpfs0:testfileset --files 1:1
```

By default root may exceed the quota, so root can create files here, but others will be denied:

```
# touch testfileset/file1 testfileset/file2 testfileset/file3

# chown nobody testfileset
# sudo -u nobody touch testfileset/file4 testfileset/file5 testfileset/file6
touch: cannot touch 'testfileset/file4': Disk quota exceeded
touch: cannot touch 'testfileset/file5': Disk quota exceeded
touch: cannot touch 'testfileset/file6': Disk quota exceeded
```

The rest is just normal file permissions..